# How do I log unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, global-asax

Here's what I'm trying to do in my Global.asax.vb:

```
Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
        routes.MapRoute( _
            "Error", _
            "error.html", _
            New With {.controller = "Error", _
                      .action = "FriendlyError"} _
        )
        ...
        'other routes go here'
        ...
    End Sub

    Sub Application_Start()
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub

    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ...
        'code here logs the unhandled exception and sends an email alert'
        ...
        Server.Transfer("http://www.example.com/error.html")
    End Sub

End Class
```

But that Server.Transfer fails:

> `Invalid path for child request 'http://www.example.com/error.html'. A virtual path is expected.`

How do I fix this?  Or, what's a better way for me to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found this on Scott Hanselman's blog [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) called [ELMAH](http://www.raboof.com/projects/Elmah/) which is an Error Logger/Handler that you can use without having to change your code.  You might want to look into it, since it seems to work nicely with MVC.

Comment: We use a modified version of ELMAH here on Stack Overflow - it's very good.

Comment: @Jarrod - What types of things have you guys included in your fork?

Comment: ELMAH rules - its more helpful than log4net was. IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is an excellent error handler for catching unhandled exceptions.  It plugs seamlessly into your web application via HttpModules and has various options for notification and logging.

**Features:**

- SQL, XML, SQLite, InMemory Logging
- Email notification
- RSS feed
- Detailed! logging of exceptions
- Easy integration
- Error Signalling - signal the error handler of an error while "dieing nicely" for the user

And FYI, SO uses ELMAH, albeit a forked version. This is the best [architectural explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx) and [setup tutorial](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specifiy a virtual path, i.e. a path relative to the application base (i.e. no paths external to the app), so something like:
Server.Transfer("error.html")
or
Server.Transfer("/error.html")
or
Server.Transfer("~/error.html")

Comment: "~/error.html":  Error executing child request for /error.html.

Comment: "/error.html":  Error executing child request for /error.html.

Comment: I just did the same tests, they all worked, except if I put in an incorrect filename, then I get "Error executing child request for /test_WRONG.html.". Are you sure that error.html exists in the root?

Comment: It does not exist.  It should route to the FriendlyError view of the  Error controller.

Answer (score 2):

By default, ASP.NET MVC applications have a view Shared/Error.aspx, inheriting from

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo>
```

If your controller uses the attribute [HandleError], all exceptions will continue to bubble until caught, and they will end up on that page.

I simply added an inline Page_Load (valid in this case since it's the end of the line):

```
<script runat="server">
  Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyExceptionHandlerService.LogException("exceptionsource", this.Model.Exception)
  End Sub
</script>
```

After it, the friendly "Sorry..." message.  It definitely looks like ELMAH is more robust, but for my needs, this was sufficient.